# How to get messages number in azure queue

Tags: azure, azure-queues

Please advice how to calculate how much messages are in the azure queue

Comment: You will notice (as I did the other night) that when retrieving messages via the GetMessages method, the maximum batch size supported by Queue Service API in a single dequeue operation is limited to 32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [CloudQueue.RetrieveApproximateMessageCount()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudqueue.retrieveapproximatemessagecount.aspx)